# HtmlUnit login form, problems with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, forms, authentication, htmlunit

Hi I'm trying to use `htmlunit` to log in to a server. When I disable `htmlunit's` javascript support my program succeeds in posting the login information, but redirects me to another page that says "Because you are not using javascript you must press continue once". Automating the clicking of this continue button leads to a 404 page even in a normal browser, so this is not an option.

So -- I need to set up javascript in order to perform the authentication. Can someone please help me with this? Below is my code, the stack trace of the errors thrown, and the html source I am working with. Thanks in advance.

```
    WebClient wc = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
    wc.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    wc.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    HtmlPage page0 = wc.getPage("https://my.usc.edu/wp/shiblogin.do?r=/wp/student/searchForm.do");
    HtmlPage page1 = wc.getPage("https://shibboleth.usc.edu/idp/Authn/UserPassword");

    HtmlForm loginForm = page1.getForms().get(0);

    //HtmlSubmitInput button = loginForm.getInputByValue("Login");
    HtmlTextInput userField = loginForm.getInputByName("j_username");
    HtmlPasswordInput passwordField = loginForm.getInputByName("j_password");

    userField.setValueAttribute("username");
    passwordField.setValueAttribute("password");

    HtmlPage page2 = (HtmlPage) loginForm.getInputByValue("Login").click();

    String htmlBody = page2.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();

    System.out.println(page2.asText());
    System.out.println(htmlBody);
```

---

> 

```
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 404 >/wp/student/searchForm.do/index.html for >https://my.usc.edu/wp/student/searchForm.do/index.html
>   at >com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.throwFailingHttpStatusCodeExceptionIfNecessary(WebCli>ent.java:543)
>   at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2228)
>   at >com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLFormElement.submit(HTMLFormElement.jav>a:310)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at >sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:137)
>   ... 34 more
>== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==
>function () {
>   [native code, arity=0]
>}

>======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

---

```
<form id="loginform" action="/idp/Authn/UserPassword" method="post" onsubmit="if (this.getAttribute('submitted')) return false; this.setAttribute('submitted','true'); document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;" >

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>USCnet Login</legend>
                    <table id="login">
                        <tr>
                            <th><label for="j_username">USC NetID:</label></th>
                            <td><input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" maxlength="12" value="" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><label for="j_password">Password:</label></th>
                            <td><input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: What is the javascript that is stopping the form from successfully posting with Javascript support enabled?

Comment: the first line of the html.

Comment: onsubmit="if (this.getAttribute('submitted')) return false; this.setAttribute('submitted','true'); document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;"